# Unusual symbol on schematic

Tags: identification, symbol, schematic

[image][image: Unusual symbol]

What this is symbol?  It's in series with a miniature incandescent lamp and I do not recognize it.

Comment: In which device is this, what era device it is, in which part of the world the device is made/designed/manufactured and is it a wiring diagram, schematic or other diagram? What else you can tell about the device, if you have a link to the service manual it might help.

Comment: Is your diagram annotated?

Comment: This is in several drawings going back at least 30 years yet also used on new drawings as well. It's for lighted panels in aircraft. The circuits themselves are typically just parallel subminiature incandescent lamps wired to a connector. The schematics only show one lamp when there are actually many lamps. No annotations on the drawing.

Comment: Fuse?  Though I could not find that exact symbol in my ANSII standard.

Comment: 2 wild guesses.   First, maybe it's a 'buffer'.   It looks like a logic AND gate with two inversions.   The electrical purpose would be to increase available power to the bulb.  It's common to not draw out all the electrical connections on logic gates as they are "presumed obvious to one skilled in the art".    Second guess, maybe its supposed to be a MECHANICAL thing, specifically it's the parabolic reflector thats likely positioned behind the light to make it appear brighter.  Sure is shaped like one....

Comment: No fuses in any of the actual circuits, just the lamps, wires (or PCB) and then wires to the connector.  No reflectors in any of these parts, either.  I thought maybe a buffer of some sort, yet nothing is in the actual parts.  I also did think that it is maybe some weird symbol for "more than one" yet never found anything similar.  So your guesses are not that wild, lol.  Another thought that it was meant to convey there will be a large inrush current when turned on, yet that should be fairly obvious from the lamp symbol.

Comment: Could you put the part in context in the question, ie. show a circuit that uses it?

Comment: @OskarSkog image added to post.  They show only the connector pins, a lamp symbol (even though there are usually several in parallel) and the odd symbol, all in series.

Comment: Well, it does not look like it's a symbol related to electronics or electrical schematics. It is likely some symbol in avionics diagrams, such as cable harness wiring diagram or other system diagram. As said before, it can signal something non-electrical such as mechanical pass through or sleeving.

Comment: Thinking physically, could it be a bulb-flasher?  They symbol looks somewhat like a digital "driver" of sorts, or perhaps more physically "a keyed thing that plugs into a socket with round pins."

Comment: This is for backlighting the characters in panels, similar in function to lighting the dashboard on your car at night. It could be related to something mechanical, I just don't know of any common mechanical components that have special symbols.

Comment: Or perhaps, for lighted panels in aircraft, it's a buzzer or indicator that only activates when the bulb burns out?  Grasping at straws here.

Comment: Straws are always good. In these panels there are no other circuits or mechanical items.